# devise config.timeout_in not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, settimeout

I am unable  to timeout session with devise session timeout in initializers/devise.rb

I set

```
config.timeout_in = 1.minute
```

in initializers/devise.rb and i signin with one user and stayed idle for 2 minutes. This is suppose to invalidate current session and again prompt to ask for user credentials but the session never dies.

Am i doing something wrong or missing anything?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry fixed with little googling. I had missed to keep timeoutable field in my model. When i had kept it in a model it solved my problem.

Comment: +1 - You should add that as an answer (with an example of the code to put in your model) and accept it. I'd vote it up. Had the same problem, had to google around to find out what you meant by "keep timeoutable feild" in the model. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You need to include `:timeoutable` in your Model, i.e.

```
devise :timeoutable
```

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Timeoutable

Answer (score 5):

The timeout_in and remember_me will not work together.

Timeoutable incompatible with the remember_me checkbox. You can have one, but not both.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation that states this?

Comment: @aaronmallen https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb#L26