# RoR 3.2 devise (3.2.2) :timeoutable not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

After checking a few questions like:

[rails 3.1, devise gem, :timeoutable is not working, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331701/rails-3-1-devise-gem-timeoutable-is-not-working-why)

[Devise - Timeout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510959/devise-timeout-not-working)

[devise config.timeout_in not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184567/devise-config-timeout-in-not-working)

[How to configure time out using devise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495390/how-to-configure-time-out-using-devise)

I have set my user model with :timeoutable

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :rememberable, :demo_authenticatable, :api_authenticatable,:registerable,
:recoverable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable
```

And I have also uncomented the timeout_in line in the devise.rb file

```
config.timeout_in = 1.minutes
```

I also tryed setting the timeout_in property in the user model, but i keep beeing logged in

Any clues?

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you're expecting it to present you with the login page when you refresh, remove the timeout part from your model and put it in devise.rb NOT development.rb & restart rails server.
`config.timeout_in = 1.hour`